# Bootstrap 4 - creating dynamic carousel

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, dynamic, carousel

I am trying to fill a Bootstrap Carousel dynamically. I have seen a prior stackoverflow article, that would seem like it would work, but cannot seem to append to the carousel. The carousel needs 6 items across.

I am filling from an Ajax call below. the script goes through without an error, however the carousel does not appear. the iconlocation indicated below is coming back as image1.jpg, image2.jpg etc  any help is appreciated!

I have tried just replacing the image portion of the div and just manipulating existing images in the carousel to new links and images. It does not seem to refresh or show dynamically

```
<script>

    function GetCarouselData() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "Get",
            url: "api/UserApps/username/",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        }).done(
            function (m) {
                for (var i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
                    var carstr = '<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-12"><a href="#"><img src="~/images/"' + m[i].iconLocation + '" alt="" /></a></div > ';
                    $(carstr).appendTo(".carousel1Row");

              }
            $('.carouselitem1').first().addClass('active');
            $('#carousel1').carousel();
                return true;

            })
            .fail(function (data) {
                alert("fail");
            });
    }

</script>
```

and the carousel looks like below:

```
<div id="carousel1" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div  class="carousel-item active">
            <div id="carousel1Row" class="row">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel1" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel1" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

my issue.  .appendTo(".carousel1Row") should have been .appendTo("#carousel1Row")